# Can you specify the path to exe in qmake?

Tags: qt, qmake

Let's talk about it in linux terms. I have a ".so" file. I want to make the executable dependent on it, look for it in the same directory. How do you do it through qmake? Or can this only be achieved through the use of QLibrary?

For example, when you have a ".so" file and want to use it in your project, in qmake you write:

```
LIBS += -L"path to the folder that contains your .so" -lSoName
```

But the path is hardcoded, as you can see, and I'm wondering what to write there to make the executable look for the ".so" in the same directory.

Comment: Do you want your .so to be found in same directory  during runtime or compile time?

Comment: @NulledPointer runtime.

Answer (score 2):

**You use [RPATH](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html)**

You can configure your binary or library to find shared library (or dll) in current directory using RPATH directive that is emedded in the binary itself which the loader respects at runtime

1- Add the following in your  `.pro` file

```
unix {
        message("Adding RPATH to the app")
        QMAKE_LFLAGS    +=  -Wl,-rpath=\'\$$ORIGIN/\'
        QMAKE_RPATH     =
}
```

This will set RPATH of executable to current directory and your executable will first try to look for that `.so` in your current directory and then in standard directory (this process is explained [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html))

2- After you compile and create binary VERIFY that RPATH is set correctly

```
objdump -x <path/to/binary> |grep RPATH
```

it should say `$ORIGIN`

Compile time configuration:

```
CXXFLAGS += -L"/path/to/libmarylin.so/file" -lmarylin
```

Comment: What about "LIBS +=" ? What goes on that line? I just wrote "-lSoName" and it doesn't work.

Comment: Leave that line like you specified and try my suggestion. BTW if your library usually is named "libmarylin.so" then you should say "-lmarylin" (dropping the "lib" part)

Comment: I just did and it doesn't work. Can't find the ".so". Does this work for you?

Comment: Try changing LIBS with CXXFLAGS

Comment: I know about the "lib" part, by the way. What do you mean by your last message?

Comment: @Pavel Please remove LIBS from .pro file and add CXXFLAGS in your .pro file as i mentioned in my answer

Comment: @NulledPointer should work with `LIBS` instead of `CXXFLAGS` for linking too. `--rpath` should only affect library path during runtime, shouldn't it?

Comment: @SebastianLange OP requested runtime and then complained it doesnt even compile

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it.

If the executable is going in the current directory, just do `LIBS += -L$$(PWD) -lSoName`.

If you're putting the executable into some other sub-directory, specified by some `qmake` variable like `DESTDIR`, use `LIBS += -L$$(DESTDIR)` (or whatever variable holds that directory).

Alternatively, you can add the directory with the executable to the runtime path of the executable, which gives the dynamic linker a list of directories to search for any unresolved libraries at runtime. This can be done with `QMAKE_RPATHDIR += -L$$(PWD)` and `LIBS += -lSoName`, which will tell the linker to look for unresolved libraries in the current directory where `qmake` is run.

Some operating systems may also include the current directory in the runtime search path for libraries by default, in which case just doing `LIBS += -lSoName` should be sufficient. That is platform-dependent, though, while the above solutions are not.

Comment: I was talking about the directory of the executable, and not the directory of qmake. With QLibrary at runtime I can get the path to executable and load .so from the same directory, but I was wondering if it can be done through qmake.

Comment: @Pavel linked shared libraries always have to be beside the executable or in the global path. The path given to qmake is just for linking, not for executing. The shared library will always be looked for within the same directory and the global path (win) or the global lib-path (lin) during execution (default behaviour)

Comment: @SebastianLange thanks a lot! I just learned this stuff in terms of qt, but not in terms of g++, so I don't know what exactly goes on behind the scenes yet. Now you explained.